# Combination of 2 itemsets is created in the other way around

Tags: python, combinations

I'm new to Python and I'm writing code to combine items. So I have for example this array

```
[1, 12, 13, 15, 21, 24,28, 29, 35, 36]
```

I'm generating my set of items this way:

```py
for e1, e2 in combinations(array, 2):
    item = e1| e2 # union of two sets
```

so I get

```
[1,12] [1,13] [1,15] [1,21]
```

and then

```
[24,1]
```

instead of

```
[1,24]
```

and then

```
[1,28]
```

the combination is pretty normal. In all iterations i got this issue, do you know why this happens.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That code can't possibly work. That's not "union of two sets", that's bitwise or since you're dealing with numbers, not sets.

Comment: `itertools.combinations(array, 2)` for me outputs `1,12; 1,13; 1,15; 1,21; 1,24; ...`.

Comment: Why does the order matter? The `|` operation is commutative.

Comment: Hi Barmar, actually the order doesnt matter. I just wanted to have a sorted list of itemsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am rather sure your confusion is caused by the following:

```
>>> {1, 12}
{1, 12}
>>> {1, 13}
{1, 13}
# ...
>>> {1, 21}
{1, 21}
>>> {1, 24}
{24, 1}  # first odd example
```

Well, sets are inherently unordered, so `{1, 24}` and `{24, 1}` are just two representations of exactly the same thing.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the explanation, then I dont need to worry about. I just was wondering why this only happens with a certain element. So I must assume that's the way the algorithm within the function itertools.combinations compute this.

Comment: No, the `combinations` are ordered. Just turning them into a set will lose that ordering information. It's the set implementation's internal workings that cause whatever order comes up there.

Answer (score 0):

As @schwobaseggl said, sets are unordered and if you want it to be ordered you should  use `sorted(item)` or `list(item)`